# Read from command prompt to batch file

Tags: batch-file

everyone, I need to solve a problem.

I need to write to a command prompt like this.

с:>convert.bat "Ao äia õe uue oaõieaia õueaua ööau"

And the script needs to show to the user string which I write to there.

How I can do this?

Comment: [How-to: Pass Command Line arguments to a Windows batch file.](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run time arguments in a batch file are managed with %1, %2....

That means, if you access %1 inside the batch file, you can get the first argument passed in.

welcome.bat :

```
@echo Hello, %1
```

Run `welcome.bat "World"` will give the output:

```
Hello, World.
```

Comment: 1) The output would be `Hello, "World"`. 2) there are just 9 named arguments `%1`...`%9`. `%11` is translated to `%1` appended by a literal `1` (just out of curiosity: where did you get the `255` from? I just managed to get 4095 parameters, but the limiting factor here is only the maximal line length). (to access more parameters, you need the [shift](https://ss64.com/nt/shift.html) command)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I have edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: does not work with most poisonous chars, but +1. A recommendation to improve this answer is to use `DELAYEDEXPANSION` and `ECHO ON` with `REM` to pipe to file, and read the file using `SET /P`. Also, use `ECHO(`.

Answer (score 0):

**@Santhosh J**'s answer breaks with parameters like `&`, `"`, `|`... But this one doesn't.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::Redirect to file
>args.tmp (
SETLOCAL DISABLEEXTENSIONS
prompt #
@echo on
FOR %%a in (%%a) do REM # %1#
@echo off
ENDLOCAL
)

::Read file using SET /P
<args.tmp (
set /p arg=
set /p arg=
)

::Delete temp file
del /f /q args.tmp

::Trim prompt and surrounding #s
set "arg=!arg:~7,-2!"

::Print
ECHO(!arg!
ENDLOCAL
```

Based on [Foolproof counting of arguments](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=13002#p13002).

`SETLOCAL DISABLEEXTENSIONS` disables modifiers like `%%~dpa`.

`FOR %%a in (%%a) do ...`

1. Replaces the **FOR-variable** `%%a` with the **string** `%%a`
2. echoes the `...` when `ECHO` is on.

`REM # %1#` protects it from parameters like `/?`

At last, `SET /P` provides a reliable way to read the file.